# how to use params in the base URL angular 4+?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am working on an app that will have URLs specific to both company and country.

> mysite.com/company/country

Is there a way to add the parameters to the base URL rather than adding them to the paths directly?

Comment: Can you give us an example of how you would **Like** it to work?

Comment: the base path for any route in the app should be  mysite/:company/:country'.  The problem I have is that I cant figure out how to make the params part of the base rather than part of standard router paths

Comment: to clarify I want "/login" to automatically be ":company/:country/login"

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

To call router:

```
this.router.navigate(['/myUrlpath', "company_name", "country_name"]);
```

In routes.ts:

```
{ path: 'myUrlpath/:company/:country', component: sampleComponent},
```